# How to extract the value of the loss function of Cox models from glmnet in R?

Tags: r, glmnet, cox-regression

I fit a given data using Cox model via glmnet R package and my
little R example is:

```
    library(fastcox);data(FHT);attach(FHT)  #   
    library(glmnet)
    library(survival)
    fit = glmnet(x,Surv(y,status),family="cox",alpha=1)
```

From the help document, we know glmnet fits penalized models like

```
    -loglik/nobs + λ*penalty
```

i.e.,  `objective function = loss function + penalty function`.
I want to fetch `-loglik/nobs` (loss function value, 
the negative partial log-likelihood of the fitted model
or two term
Taylor series expansions of the log likelihoods) from the `fit` object. 
Any idea? Tks

BTW, we also tried

```
fit0 = glmnet(x,Surv(y,status),family="cox",alpha=1,lambda=0)
```

according to `-loglik/nobs + λ*penalty`, but it shows errors.